# Double single quote into double quote

Tags: python, double, quote

I try to use this command into python, but i have problem with single quote into double quote :

```
os.system("psql -h localhost -U postgres -d mabase -c "COPY tmp_import_csv FROM '/var/www/wwwdata/sum_area.csv' DELIMITER ' ' CSV HEADER;"")
```

The quote problem is in this part : **DELIMITER ' '**

How can i make it work ?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not with the nested double quotes? Shouldn't the inner ones be escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
os.system("psql -h localhost -U postgres -d mabase -c \"COPY tmp_import_csv FROM '/var/www/wwwdata/sum_area.csv' DELIMITER ' ' CSV HEADER;\"")
```

I escaped the double quotes.

Comment: Its works ! Thank you very much Sifu :)
Escape double quote is a great solution.